# PowerShell HTML report output format

Tags: html, powershell, format, report, output

I need some help on the report output for a PowerShell script I'm putting together. The script get's information from a computer on the following items.

Last Rebooted by
Uptime
Pending Reboot
Patching Information

The problem I'm having is with the "Patching Information" output. The information I want returned under this heading is "Hotfixid","description","installedby","installedon"

If I specify one value such as "Updates.hotfixid" I get the results but If I try adding the others I get returned System.Object[] System.Object[].

Also the output under this heading wraps but i'd like it to list.

Below is the script

```
    $comps = Get-Content 'c:\temp\comp.txt'

    $total = $null

    $html = @'
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>
    <title> Server Maintenance Report</title>
    <STYLE TYPE="text/css">
    <!--
    td {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-top: 1px solid #999999;
    border-right: 1px solid #999999;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999999;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    }
    body {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    table {
    border: thin solid #000000;
    }
    -->
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table width='100%'>
    <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
    <td colspan='7' height='25' align='center'><strong><font color="#003399" size="4" face="tahoma"> Report </font></strong></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table width='100%'><tbody>
          <tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>
          <td width='14%' height='15' align='center'> <strong> <font color="#003399" size="2" face="tahoma" >Server Name</font></strong></td>
          <td width='14%' height='15' align='center'> <strong> <font color="#003399" size="2" face="tahoma" >Last Rebooted By</font></strong></td>
          <td width='16%' height='15' align='center'> <strong> <font color="#003399" size="2" face="tahoma" >Uptime</font></strong></td>
          <td width='8%' height='15' align='center'> <strong> <font color="#003399" size="2" face="tahoma" >Pending Reboot</font></strong></td>
          <td width='50%' height='15' align='center'> <strong> <font color="#003399" size="2" face="tahoma" >Patching Information</font></strong></td>
          </tr>" 
    </table>
    <table width='100%'><tbody>
    '@

    Function Uptime($comp){
            function WMIDateStringToDate($Bootup) {
             [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime($Bootup)
            }
            $NameSpace = "Root\CIMV2"
            $wmi = [WMISearcher]""
            #$wmi.options.timeout = '0:0:30' #set timeout to 30 seconds
            $query = 'Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem'
            $wmi.scope.path = "\\$comp\$NameSpace"

            $wmi.query = $query
            Try{
                $wmiresult = $wmi.Get()
                foreach ($wmioutput in $wmiresult){
                   $Bootup = $wmioutput.LastBootUpTime
                   $LastBootUpTime = WMIDateStringToDate($Bootup)
                   $now = Get-Date
                   $Reporttime = $now - $lastBootUpTime
                   $d = $Reporttime.Days
                   $h = $Reporttime.Hours
                   $m = $Reporttime.Minutes
                   $time = "Up for: {0} days, {1} hours, {2:N0} minutes" -f $d,$h,$m
                   return $time 
                }
            }
            Catch [Exception] {
                $uperr = '<font color="#FF0000"> RPC Issue : </font>'+ $_
                return $uperr 
            }
        }

    Function RebootedBy($comp){
            try {
            gwmi win32_ntlogevent -filter "LogFile='System' and EventCode='1074' and Message like '%restart%'" -ComputerName $comp | 
            Where {$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.TimeGenerated) -gt $lastBootUpTime}  | 
            select User,@{n="Time";e={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.TimeGenerated)}} -First 1
            }
            Catch [Exception] {
                $uperr = '<font color="#FF0000"> RPC Issue : </font>'+ $_
                return $uperr 
            }
        }


    Function Updates ($comp){
            try {
            $date = Get-Date '26/09/2013'
            (Get-HotFix -ComputerName $comp| where-object {$_.hotfixid -ne "file 1"} | where "InstalledOn" -gt $date | Select hotfixid,description,installedby,@{l="InstalledOn";e={[DateTime]::Parse($_.psbase.properties["installedon"].value,$([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo("en-US")))}} )
            }
            Catch [Exception] {
                $uperr = '<font color="#FF0000"> RPC Issue : </font>'+ $_
                return $uperr 
            }
         }


    function PendingReboot ($comp){
        process {
            try {
                $WMI_OS = ""
                $RegCon  = ""
                $WMI_OS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $comp -ErrorAction Stop
                if ($?){
                try{ 
                    $RegCon = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]"LocalMachine",$comp) 
                    If ($WMI_OS.BuildNumber -ge 6001){ 
                        $RegValueSetupex = ""
                        $RegValuePFRO2k8 = ""
                        $RegSubKeySM = $RegCon.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\") 
                        $RegValueSetupex = $RegSubKeySM.GetValue("SetupExecute",$null) 
                        if ($RegValueSetupex){
                            $RegValueSetupex = $true
                        }

                        $RegSubKeySM = $RegCon.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\") 
                        $RegValuePFRO2k8 = $RegSubKeySM.GetValue("PendingFileRenameOperations",$null) 
                        if ($RegValuePFRO2k8 ){
                            $RegValuePFRO2k8  = $true
                        }

                        $RegCon.Close()

                        if ( $RegValueSetupex -eq $true -or $RegValuePFRO2k8 -eq $true){
                            return '<font color="#FF0000">'+$true
                        }
                        else {
                            return $false                           
                        }
                    }
                    else{   
                        $RegValuePFRO2k3 = $false;
                        $RegCon = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]"LocalMachine","$comp") 
                        $RegSubKeySM = $RegCon.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\") 
                        $RegValuePFRO2k3 = $RegSubKeySM.GetValue("PendingFileRenameOperations",$null) 
                        $RegCon.Close()
                        If ($RegValuePFRO2k3) { 
                            return  '<font color="#FFFF00">'+$true; 
                        }
                        else {
                            return $false; 
                        } 
                    }

                }
                catch {
                    return '<font color="#7CFC00">'+"Remote Registry Service OK"
                }
                }
                else {
                    throw $error[0].Exception
                }
            }   
            catch {
                    return '<font color="#FF0000">'+"RPC Issue"         
            }
        }
    }


    $i=0 # for Progress bar

    foreach($comp in $comps){
        $i++
        $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue" 
        Write-Progress   -Activity "Report v1.0" -Status ("Checking : {0}" -f $comp) -PercentComplete ($i/$comps.count*100) -Id 0 
        $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
        #region Var_Nulling :p  
        $Reporttimestatus  = $null

        #endregion
        $Reporttimestatus = uptime -comp $comp
        $RebootedBy = RebootedBy $comp
        $Pending = PendingReboot -comp $comp
        $Updates = Updates -comp $comp

        $newobj = $null
        $newobj = new-object psobject
        $newobj | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "Server" -value $comp 
        $newobj | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "Uptime" -value $Reporttimestatus
        $newobj | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "RebootedBy" -value $RebootedBy.User , $RebootedBy.Time
        $newobj | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "PendingReboot" -value $Pending
        $newobj | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "Updates" -value $Updates.hotfixid
        #, $Updates.description , $Updates.installedby , $Updates.InstalledOn

        $htmlserver = $newobj.Server
        $htmluptime = $newobj.Uptime
        $htmlrebootedby = $newobj.RebootedBy
        $htmlpendingreboot =  $newobj.PendingReboot
        $htmlupdates = $newobj.Updates

    $current = "
            <tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>
            <td width='14%' align='center'>$htmlserver</td>
            <td width='14%' align='center'>$htmlrebootedby</td>
            <td width='16%' align='center'>$htmluptime</td>
            <td width='8%' align='center'>$htmlpendingreboot</td>
            <td width='50%' align='left'>$htmlupdates</td>
            </tr> "

        $total += $current

    }

    $HTMLEnd = @"
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    "@

    $MainHtml= $html + $total + $HTMLEnd
    $MainHtml  | Out-File "c:\temp\Report.html" -Append
```

Comment: -1. Don't just dump a ton of code and ask people to fix it for you.  Create a minimal snippet that reproduces the specific issue you are facing, with as few external dependencies as possible.  This is a good exercise in general, and in the process you might discover the resolution yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign Updates an array of arrays value because in Powershell V3 $arrayOfObject.propertyName outputs the property value for every element in that array.  The feature is called member enumeration. That is why the formatting you're getting isn't ideal.

Why don't you assign the "Updates" field the value $updates e.g.:

```
$newobj | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "Updates" -value $Updates
```

That will contain an array of objects, each of which will have properties hotfixid, description, installeby, installedOn.  Then in your `$current` HTML fragment, I would iterate over each update and spit out each individual field.  Perhaps a table within a table.

```
$current = @"
        <tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>
        <td width='14%' align='center'>$htmlserver</td>
        <td width='14%' align='center'>$htmlrebootedby</td>
        <td width='16%' align='center'>$htmluptime</td>
        <td width='8%' align='center'>$htmlpendingreboot</td>
        </tr> 
        $(foreach ($update in $updates) {
          "<tr><td>$($update.hotfixid)</td>"
          "<td>$($update.description)</td>"
          "<td>$($update.installedby)</td>"
          "<td>$($update.installedon)</td></tr>"
        })
"@
```

Comment: Thanks...adding -value $Updates was what I was referring to.